# Logging using Serilog not creating logs in .NET Core 6 using 'Serilog.Sinks.File' option, while working in .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-5.0, serilog-sinks-file

I am using Serilog.Sinks.File in .NET Core 5 and it is working fine.

In .NET Core 5, I am using the subsequent configuration,
startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
          .CreateLogger();
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
    }
```

And appsettings.json file has

```
 "Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"Override": {
  "Microsoft": "Warning"
},
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.File"
],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "C:\\logs\\myapi\\log-{Date}.txt"
    }
  }
]
```

}

The Nuget package used

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
```

Now, I am trying to achieve the same thing in **.NET Core 6** application. I have kept the appsettings.json file as is it and used the code in Program.cs

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
  .Enrich.FromLogContext()
  .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

But the application is not creating log files. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing [`Serilog.AspNetCore`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) and then add then change `builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);` to:

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```